# Python code to get a value from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to run this code in JavaScript ***from PYTHON*** maybe with  (PyV8, js2py, BeautifulSoup or seleniumto) to get the image path and print or store it in csv file, so I want to print image path like "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo~~"

Thanks a lot and happy new year!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
        ['2004', 1000, 400],
        ['2005', 1170, 460],
        ['2006', 660, 1120],
        ['2007', 1030, 540]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
        curve_chart.innerHTML = '<img  src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
        console.log(curve_chart.innerHTML);
      });
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so what is your question? `chart.getImageURI()` returns that path which is part of that `google` object (which is part of that library). I really don't understand your question.

Comment: I guess you are using a Python framework for the backend (Django or Flask)?

Comment: "I want run it th[r]ough python" What do you mean? Python is not Javascript.

Comment: it's a javascript code, right but I want to use python code (PyV8, js2py, BeautifulSoup or selenium) to run it and store the image path in csv